convolution type of maximal function
Let
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x(\log x)^{2}}$$
for $0<x\leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x>\frac{1}{2}$, and extended to $x<0$ by $f(x)=-f(-x)$. Then $f$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$, with $\int f=0$. Let
$$M(f)=\sup_{\varepsilon>0}|f*\Phi_{\varepsilon}(x)|,$$
$$\Phi_{\varepsilon}=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\Phi\left(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}\right),$$
where $\Phi$ is a $C^{1}$ function with compact support.
Show that
$$M(f)\geq \frac{c}{|(x\log|x|)|}$$
for $|x|\leq \frac{1}{2}$, for some $\Phi\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ with compact support.
This is Exercise 17 in the Chapter 2 of stein's book, functional analysis. I can prove this if $M(f)$ is hardy maximal function, but for convolution type of maximal function, I don't think this is correct.
It would be very helpful with detailed proof.   I am really stuck, many thanks!

Here is a helpful post relate to same question:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514620/error-in-stein-shakarchi-exercise-on-h1-mathbbr-and-l-log-l?rq=1
